# Is it possible to make a customised Wordpress, seo friendly, url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change the customized URl of wordpress, where I pass the id in querystring to get data from my custom table. Now i want to see the title instead of that id.

Ex. My site link id http://xyz.com/?page_id=1&pid=12
Now if i try the wordpress permalink it will convert the wp page only like http://xyz.com/test?pid=12

What can i do to make the URl like http://xyz.com/test/title. Where title is stored in database for pid=12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible and actually pretty easy. Go to `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and look for the custom option that you want. You must have access to the server to update the `.htaccess` file. Here is more [info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Answer (score 0):

if you want the name of your page to appear as in:
http://www.xyz.com/about/

instead of something like:
http://www.xyz.com/?page_id=398

1. login to your back end of wordpress
2. under the settings menu(on left side) click permalinks
3. click custom structure and in the text field type in:

/%postname%/