# Wordpress custom table make seo friendly url

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I have a one website in wordpress I used in this custom table, In this there is so many records, so for a see single record I used this url http://www.example.com/view-pitch/?pitchid=36 , but I want to make it seo friendly url like this http://www.example.com/view-pitch/single-record-title.

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: add sku for each product  . use product sku .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a customised Wordpress, seo friendly, url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336948/is-it-possible-to-make-a-customised-wordpress-seo-friendly-url)

Answer (score 1):

in your site login to `admin` and goto the `setting` -> `permalink` and Select the `post name`

[image]

And `Save Change`